# when i try to run electron application in mac it give: Error:trust_store_mac.cc(838) Error parsing certificate: Error: Failed parsing extensions

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have developed an application using Electron.js and JavaScript on a Windows machine. Now, I need to create a macOS build for the application. However, when I attempt to run the application on a Mac, I encounter a certification error that looks like this:

```
https://staging5.onescreensolutions.com/b/signin
[2299:0811/121118.975792:ERROR:trust_store_mac.cc(838)] Error parsing certificate:
ERROR: Failed parsing extensions
```

i did not added any kind of certification in that application How did it come from

Comment: I assume your app is trying to load the URL you provided in the error message? If so, check if you can visit the page in the OS's browser. If not, there's something wrong with the SSL certificate of the webpage.